# OSX pip always uses Python2.7 and ignores my 3.6 install

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I installed pip through `brew`, and I can't get it to use python 3 instead of 2.7. Here's the information I think might be relevant to demonstrate what's happening.

```
$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
$ pip2 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
$ pip3 -V
-bash: pip3: command not found
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ sudo python3 get-pip.py 
The directory '/Users/tj/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/tj/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages


$ sudo easy_install3 pip
sudo: easy_install3: command not found
$ sudo easy_install-3.6 pip
sudo: easy_install-3.6: command not found
$ sudo easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 9.0.1
Processing pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
pip 9.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

I tried everything I could find online with no luck. The main symptom of this problem is when I use pip to install a package, it always goes into 2.7 (or fails to install because numpy is deprecated or something like that).

Comment: I don't know about OS X but on *NIX systems `pip` is `pip2` while `pip3` is the Python 3's `pip`. So, try using `pip3`.

Comment: `brew install python3`, should provide you with `pip3`

Comment: pip3 command not found, I have done `brew install python3` and it just says it's already installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On OSX, brew (or other) python 2.7/3 is installed separately to the older version of 2.7 that comes with OSX. Trust me when I say you DO NOT WANT TO MESS WITH IT.

Try typing pip3

```
$ pip3 --version   
$ pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Whereas pip (for 2.7) is not even installed.,

```
$ pip --version
$ zsh: command not found: pip
```

Even if you try:

```
$ brew install pip
```

Leads to

```
If you meant "pip" specifically:
Homebrew provides pip via: `brew install python`. However you will then
have two Pythons installed on your Mac, so alternatively you can install 
pip via the instructions at:
```

https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/

AS A LAST RESORT:

```
python3 -m ensurepip
```

will ensure/fix a system has it.

pip3 should be located at `/usr/local/bin/pip3`

Contents are:

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==9.0.1','console_scripts','pip3'
__requires__ = 'pip==9.0.1'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
    )
```

Comment: Yeah so the pip3 command doesn't exist. Running
    brew install python3
just says it's already installed.
I did follow the directions on that website and it said requirement already up to date

Comment: Did you install python3 via home-brew?

Comment: Check the bottom of the comment.

Comment: Yes I did install it through homebrew.
Even the ensurepip command says "Requirement already satisfied" and points to a path in /usr/local/Cellar/... I think something is pointing to /usr/local/bin/ and something else is pointing to the path in /usr/local/Cellar. I'm just not sure how to sort it out

Comment: can you try `python3 -m pip`

Comment: That does work 
    `$ python3 -m pip -V
    pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)`

but you can see it's pointing to the path at /usr/local/Cellar/ whereas if I just did "which pip" it'd point to /usr/local/bin

Comment: Personally, `brew unlink python3` `brew link python3` or a complete deinstall/reinstall would fix it. Sometimes the bootstrap scripts for python aren't found properly but the modules are k.

Comment: Tried unlinking and relinking with no luck. Do you mean a complete deinstall/reinstall of brew?

Comment: Just python3. maybe `brew doctor` would help

Comment: Ahh okay I'll try that and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Failing that, check the bottom of the answer for the correct location and contents of pip3 as it's just a bootstrap to the python module which does all the work.

Comment: The uninstall/reinstall worked! I still have no clue why, but thanks for the help!